# Fancybox 2 -- Stopping resize in gallery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to get Fancybox to stop resizing images in the gallery. I have some bigger images which need the scrolling. Here is my current fancybox jQuery:

```
$('.gallery').fancybox({
            padding: 0,
            scrolling: 'yes',

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            prevEffect : 'fade',
            nextEffect : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed : 100,

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : true,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : { 
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                },
                overlay : {
                    opacity : 0.8
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `fitToView` to `false` so:

```
$('.gallery').fancybox({

            fitToView: false, // add this

            padding: 0,
            scrolling: 'yes',

            openEffect : 'elastic',
            openSpeed  : 150,

            prevEffect : 'fade',
            nextEffect : 'none',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            closeSpeed : 100,

            closeBtn  : false,
            arrows    : true,
            nextClick : true,

            helpers : { 
                thumbs : {
                    width  : 50,
                    height : 50
                },
                overlay : {
                    opacity : 0.8
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: most likely you forgot to add the trial comma to separate this option from the next or maybe you enclosed the `false` Boolean in quotes or any other syntax issue that triggered a js error.

Answer (score 0):

autoScale property works for me.

```
$('.gallery').fancybox({
    'autoScale':false,
});
```